# computer plays movie fine but ps3 plays it with no sound?

Tags: video, ps3

i have a movie that plays fine on my computer but when i copy it to an SD card and play it in my PS3 it has no sound.

the audio format is mpeg layer-3
bit rate is 128
frame rate is 25frames/ second
data rate is 1068 kbps
video sample size is 12 bit
video compression is DivX

i got these stats by right clicking the file and viewing properties.

can i open it in some editor and re-save it? what editor?

thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this isn't exactly what you asked, but I'd like to share my own experience from playing movies on the PS3.

While Sony improves the codecs support every once in a while, it still lags far behind what can be played on the PC.
This is why I prefer (and recommend) transcoding the movie using PS3 Media Server or TVesity, and play it over the network. This would save you the trouble of "editing" movies prior to playing them on the PS3, and would also allow you to play movies which are otherwise un-playable on the PS3, such as movies packaged in MKV files.